# Add some variables to an array in a foreach loop

Tags: arrays, laravel, foreach

1 / I read a table X with multiple Join and where clause (Result is in $query1).

```
            $query1= DB::select(DB::raw(....)
```

2 / After, I do a FOREACH loop. For each selected row, I do a sum of some fields coming from a table X where columns = $ values coming from $query1.

```
    $query2 = DB::table('paris')
    ->WHERE('bet_grille_id', '=', $pari->bet_grille_id)
    ->WHERE('bet_match_id','=',$pari->bet_match_id)
    ->WHERE('bet_groupe_id','=',$pari->bet_groupe_id )
    ->WHERE('bet_status','<>','I')
    ->GROUPBY('bet_grille_id','bet_match_id')
    ->get(array(
    DB::raw('SUM(CASE WHEN bet_sens="1" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS parieur1'),
    DB::raw('SUM(CASE WHEN bet_sens="N" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS parieurn'),
    DB::raw('SUM(CASE WHEN bet_sens="2" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS parieur2')));
```

How I can move the result of my query 2 to the the result of query 1 ?

I have 
$query1 = A, B, C

$query 2 = D, E, F

At the end, I want to have $query1 = A, B, C, D, E, F

Thanks a lot for you help

Answer (score 0):

```
$query1 = array_merge($query1, $query2);
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was not clear in my explanations...$query1 is an array of 7 iterations...for each of these iterations, I run $query2. result of $query2 contains 3 values...What I want is to associate these 3 values coming from $query2 into the linked iteration of $query1..thanks

Comment: It would be helpful if you edited your question to provide some context and explanation of how this code answers the question.

Comment: @Dragonthoughts In fact, I read a table to build a listbox : $lstbx_groupes = DB::table('groupes as GR') ->select('GR.id','GR.grp_nm_groupe') ->join('tts_grpusers as GU','GU.gru_groupe_id','=','GR.id') ->where('GR.id','>','1') ->where('GU.gru_user_id','=','63') //@todo : replace with user variable ->Orderby ('GR.grp_nm_groupe') ->get(); and I want to add a fixed first item to this result where id = 1 and grp_nm_groupe = 'ABC' –

Answer (score 0):

In fact I have found the solution. Maybe a better one exist..but...
I put that in the foreach loop and it works fine.

$query1[$i]->pari1 = $query2[0]->parieur1;
$i++